# Wordpress ACF Toggle-Indicator

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, togglebutton

I am using Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress for sections on a page or a post on my website. But for some odd reason when I click edit page and try to open up a section, the toggle class does not work. Although when I click the edit field group icon it takes me to that field group.

I checked for jQuery errors in my console and found 0 errors.

Here is a screenshot for my page editor.

[acf page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFbup.png)

Comment: Did you already update everything? Also look at the possibility that another plugin can cause this issue. Just disable some plugins and try to see which one is causing the issue (if it is a plugin)